# How can I fix the problem react Switch Autocomplete import from react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs

I can't use Switch from react auto import, where I'm able to auto import Router from react.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router  } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
return (
<div>
  
  <Router>
      <Switch>

      </Switch>
  </Router>
  
  </div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is because you did not import the Switch component from react-router.

Per the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch), you need to do the following:

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";

let routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/about">
      <About />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/:user">
      <User />
    </Route>
    <Route>
      <NoMatch />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
);
```

So in your case:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router  } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Switch } from "react-router";

function App() {
return (
<div>
  
  <Router>
      <Switch>

      </Switch>
  </Router>
  
  </div>
 );
}
```